# centering environment - detach some text from centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to write some centered lines, but detach some of the text from the "centering" mechanism:

```
\begin{center}
some textual claim \\
$\Updownarrow$ \\
more text \\
$\Updownarrow$ - some comment \\
last text
\end{center}
```

I want the first `Updownarrow` to be over the second `Updownarrow`. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide the width of the comment

```
\begin{center}
some textual claim \\
$\Updownarrow$ \\
more text \\
$\Updownarrow$\rlap{ - some comment} \\
last text
\end{center}
```